# Why does 'sed' not extend the length of a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Given a file that has lines such as:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. 4
 5. 5
```

And I run the 'sed' command:

```
sed -i "/4/a\text\" filename.txt
```

The file ends up as:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. text
 5. 4
```

The line stating '5' is now gone.

The last line seems to have been pushed off, as if the number of lines in the file was not changed.

I have run the command without the '-i' flag, which stands for 'insert in place'.

```
sed "/3/a\text\" filename.txt > temp.txt; mv temp.txt filename.txt;
```

But received the same effect, even though an 'in place' flag was not specified. Is this 'sed's intended function? Is there a way to allow lines to be added?

Comment: The double-quoted version you've given is a shell syntax error, but even fixing that I don't replicate this with GNU sed (which I assume you're using given `a\...`?). Can you [edit] your post with a transcript showing this happening? Just copy and paste from the terminal - `cat` the file, run the `sed`. Include both what you typed and the output.

Comment: @MichaelHomer The file I'm working on existed prior to my tests, so I tried to create my own test file and you are right, it does add information properly. 

However, I am unable to duplicate this only with the file I am working on. Then, this does not appear to be a sed error, but perhaps something else. I will have to dig deeper.

Comment: Have a look for CRLF line endings.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Using your comments, I figured out my error: I was using vi to view the file until I remembered your comment about 'cat' and it showed the lines that were cut off. If you would like to add that as an answer, I will gladly complete this post!

Comment: Oh my, this is quite embarrassing. Thank you everyone for your patience with me. Forgive me for my green-ness with linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add text lines you may use simple quote .

example :

```
[root@h2g2w ~]# sed -i '/4/a\text\' toto    
[root@h2g2w ~]# cat toto                    
1                                           
2
3
4
text
5
[root@h2g2w ~]#
```

this just work as well ...
Are you sure of the sed version you're using is gnu one ?
Even double-quoted is ok (but it is a user error to use them here)

```
[root@h2g2w ~]# sed -i "/4/a\text\ " toto
[root@h2g2w ~]# cat toto
1
2
3
4
text
text
5
[root@h2g2w ~]#
```

Comment: Thank you to francois and Michael; I wasn't familiar with the 'cat' command and learned that vi only displays the top couple of lines... This is rather embarrassing, but I learned a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the commands you posted result in syntax problems for me if i put them directly into the shell.

Secondly, both commands you provided end up with the original file, 'filename.txt' being modified either directly by sed, or by other commands.

Your first example, as you surmised causes sed to modify the file directly through the use of the '-i' switch.  In your second example, 'filename.txt' is overwritten by the command `mv temp.txt filename.txt`.

Thus in either example you are seeing the expected result.

And yes, sed can be used to insert lines.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537490/insert-a-line-at-specific-line-number-with-sed-or-awk

Comment: The commands are producing the expected result, but not perhaps the desired result.  The commands are doing exactly what they've been told to do.